# How to configure settings common to many programming languages?

Tags: filetype

I edit a lot of different file types, like .c, .cc, .S, .py, .rs, .ld, plus maybe a dozen more. And I'm constantly editing new file types, so I'm adding to this list. I have settings I want to apply equivalently to all of them, like shift width.

But, I don't want to do this to *all* files, since I also edit a lot of non-programming files.

It doesn't make sense to have to create a new config every time I come across a new file type, even if I have a common base file. The `autocmd FileType` is no better since I still need to add more configuration to .vimrc for every file type.

Is there some equivalent of an emacs [`prog-mode-hook`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ProgMode) where I can configure settings once and have them apply to all programming files?

Comment: Doesn't `autocmd FileType` work for you?

Comment: @jdhao Yes, it does, but it hardly solves the problem because instead of a new file, I have to modify .vimrc and add autocmd blocks for each file type. But, I will modify my question to be more precise.

Comment: How does the emacs mechanism know a new file type is associated with a "programming file" or not?

Comment: @Roxy Then vim has to know which file is a programming file and which is not. I do not think vim has such a feature.

Comment: Make a "super auto command" preconfigured with every supported programming language filetype...in the event you start using any of those in the future...? ;) Or create a single base "after" file and symlink it for every supported file type. (Easily scritable.)

Comment: From what I can gather from a quick search in the source, it's set in the fiiletype definitions @BLayer.

Comment: @MartinTournoij If you mean there's a "isProgLang" flag or something like that, that's sort of what I was thinking. File type metadata. And an ad hoc version of that is probably the kind of solution I'd recommend here if there's nothing easier. It's better than the brute force suggestions in my previous comment.

Comment: There'd be a one-time upfront cost of collecting the filetypes. Stick 'em in a list. In the master programming file type settings file look for the file type in the list. Easy peasy. (Occasionally, you'd want to check if the needs updating...in case new relevenat file type introduced.)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Emacs, but from what I can gather the mode ("filetype" in Emacs jargon) for e.g. C (`c-mode`) inherits from `prog-mode`. It looks like you can actually inherit from multiple modes – it seems pretty neat. The closest you can get with Vim is by using dot-separated multiple filetypes (i.e `set ft=prog.c`).

Comment: Ah, so that's a level of sophistication above metadata. Not really applicable in Vim sadly...without some effort at least. (I know jack squat about emacs. Tried it once after college...hotkeys nearly broke my wrist. It's dead to me ever since.)

Comment: Couldn't it be that something like [vim-sleuth](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth) will do?

Comment: Good question. I will say that inheritance and, particularly, heuristics are not really in line with the KISS principle, though, given the relative simplicity of the problem. I'm a big proponent of KISS. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a workaround on this topic. I have a [function in my library plugin](http://%60https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/ft.vim#L53) where I register all the filetypes I've encountered that relates to text, IOW they are non-programming filetypes.

```
" Function: lh#ft#is_text(...) {{{3
function! lh#ft#is_text(...)
  let ft = a:0 == 0 ? &ft : (a:1)
  return ft =~ '^$\|text\|latex\|tex\|html\|docbk\|help\|mail\|man\|xhtml\|markdown\|rst\|gitcommit'
endfunction
```

The downside is that this list is far from being complete. Occasionally I have to register a new filetype. Fortunately my DRY policy centered around my library-plugin permits to avoid redundancy.

So, you could register an autocommand at the same (priority) level that checks whether your filetype doesn't belong to text related filetypes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use `function` with `autocommand` all in one .vimrc file.
See `:help function` or [learn_vimscript](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/23.html).

Function structure:

```
function FunctionName()
    code
endfunction
```

## Managing multiple file types

1. I use one autocmd for each type of file. Each autocmd call a specific function that will get all the needed configs.

For instance if it's a python file:

```
autcmd FileType python call Python()
```

Or if it's an exotic file extention like ".pl" for Prolog:

```
autocmd BufReadPre *.s call Swipl()
```

Like that, the all the settings/keybinding/function-call/commands for a file type will be triggered only if this file type is read by vim. (don't forget to use key bindings with `<buffer>` option if you want to edit multiple file types in one session)

2. To define a function (The first letter of the function name must take an uppercase) for example:

```
function Python()
    set wildmenu
    call CustomFunction()
    ...
endfunction
```

## Managing options for a specific group of file type

Now we can create a specific function that will contain all the settings we need to code. For instance:

```
function ProgrammingFile()
    set cindent_shiftwidth=4
    ...
endfunction
```

To add those settings to a file type settings, I just have to put this in his function settings.

```
call ProgrammingFile()
```

You can define how many function you want to make some specific groups and call them where you want.

I Hope it will help you.

Comment: Those are prolog files, not swipl (though some of them are instead perl!). Also, you seem to re-inventing the FileType and ftplugin systems, which is really not necessary. Just drop the relevant code in (eg) ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim and use setlocal/etc

Comment: @D.Ben Knoble, that's interesting. I didn't know about the ftplugin systems. I still have lot to learn. Thanks